# How to Insert data using cursor into new table having single column containing XML type data in Oracle?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I'm able to insert values into table 2 from table 1 and execute the PL/SQL procedure successfully but somehow the output is clunky. I don't know why?

Below is the code :

```
 create table airports_2_xml
 (
    airport xmltype
 );

 declare
 cursor insert_xml_cr is select * from airports_1_orcl;

  begin
  for i in insert_xml_cr
  loop
      insert into airports_2_xml values
      (
           xmlelement("OneAirport",
           xmlelement("Rank", i.Rank) ||
           xmlelement("airport",i.airport) ||
           xmlelement("Location",i.Location) || 
           xmlelement("Country", i.Country) ||
           xmlelement("Code_iata",i.code_iata) || 
           xmlelement("Code_icao", i.code_icao) ||
           xmlelement("Total_Passenger",i.Total_Passenger) ||
           xmlelement("Rank_change", i.Rank_change) ||
           xmlelement("Percent_Change", i.Percent_change)
    ));
  end loop;
 end;
 /

select * from airports_2_xml;
```

Output:

[image: Result]

Why it is showing &lt ,&gt in the output ? And why am I unable to see the output fully?

> Expected output:

```
      <OneAirport>
         <Rank>3</Rank>
         <Airport>Dubai International</Airport>
        <Location>Garhoud</Location>
        <Country>United Arab Emirates</Country>
        <Code_IATA>DXB</Code_IATA>
       <Code_ICAO>OMDB</Code_ICAO>
        <Total_passenger>88242099</Total_passenger>
       <Rank_change>0</Rank_change>
        <Percent_Change>5.5</Percent_Change>
      </OneAirport>
```

Comment: Please [post text rather than images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Also post the expected xml

Comment: Okay. I added the expected output now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below block :

```
declare
 cursor insert_xml_cr is select * from airports_1_orcl;
v_airport_xml SYS.XMLTYPE;
  begin
  for i in insert_xml_cr
  loop

  SELECT XMLELEMENT ( "OneAirport",
                             XMLFOREST(i.Rank as "Rank"
                                      ,i.airport as "Airport"
                                      ,i.Location as "Location"
                                      ,i.Country as "Country"
                                      ,i.code_iata as "Code_iata"
                                      ,i.code_icao as "code_icao"
                                      ,i.Total_Passenger as  "Total_Passenger" 
                                      , i.Rank_change as "Rank_change"
                                      ,i.Percent_change as "Percent_Change"
                                      ))
                                       into v_airport_xml
                                              FROM DUAL;

                        insert into airports_2_xml values (v_airport_xml);

  end loop;
 end;
```

Comment: Corrected by select xml tag as its incorrect ... I see Alex one simple with one insert statement rather then plsql block

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is how you are constructnig the XML. You have an outer XMLElement for `OneAirport`, and the content of that element is a single string.

You are generating individual XMLElements from the cursor fields, but then you are concenating those together, which gives you a single string which still has the angle brackets you're expecting. So you're trying to do something like, simplified a bit:

```
select
xmlelement("OneAirport", '<Rank>1</Rank><airport>Hartsfield-Jackson</airport>')
from dual;

    XMLELEMENT("ONEAIRPORT",'<RANK>1</RANK><AIRPORT>HARTSFIELD-JACKSON</AIRPORT>')  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<OneAirport>&lt;Rank&gt;1&lt;/Rank&gt;&lt;airport&gt;Hartsfield-Jackson&lt;/airp
```

and by default [XMLElement()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/XMLELEMENT.html) escapes entities in the passed-in values, so the angle-brackets are being converted to 'safe' equivalents like `&lt;`. If it didn't do that, or you told it not to with `noentityescaping`:

```
select xmlelement(noentityescaping "OneAirport", '<Rank>1</Rank><airport>Hartsfield-Jackson</airport>')
from dual;

XMLELEMENT(NOENTITYESCAPING"ONEAIRPORT",'<RANK>1</RANK><AIRPORT>HARTSFIELD-JACKS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<OneAirport><Rank>1</Rank><airport>Hartsfield-Jackson</airport></OneAirport>
```

then that would appear to be better, but you still actually have a single element with a single string (with characters that are likely to cause problems down the line), rather than the XML structure you almost certainly intended.

A simple way to get an zctual structure is with [XMLForest()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/XMLFOREST.html):

```
xmlelement("OneAirport",
  xmlforest(i.Rank, i.airport, i.Location, i.Country, i.code_iata,
    i.code_icao, i.Total_Passenger, i.Rank_change, i.Percent_change)
)
```

You don't need the cursor loop, or any PL/SQL; you can just do:

```
insert into airports_2_xml (airport)
select xmlelement("OneAirport",
  xmlforest(i.Rank, i.airport, i.Location, i.Country, i.code_iata,
    i.code_icao, i.Total_Passenger, i.Rank_change, i.Percent_change)
  )
from airports_1_orcl i;
```

The secondary issue is the display. You'll see more data if you issue some formatting commands, such as:

```
set lines 120
set long 32767
set longchunk 32767
```

Those will tell your client to retrieve and show more of the long (XMLType here) data, rather the default 80 characters it's giving you now.

Once you are generating a nested XML structure you can use [XMLSerialize()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/XMLSERIALIZE.html) to display that more readable when you query your second table.

Comment: I have one little doubt regarding same question.. like Can i use sql operations like order by, Group by and Count() operations on this xml table?